# Error : app-scripts serve unexpectedly failed.settings in ionic3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I just encountered this error while running the command `ionic serve` on my ionic 3 project.

```
[ERROR] app-scripts serve unexpectedly failed.settings: undefinedcontext: [object Object]
```

I need a quick fix cos my app failed to build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into an [article](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1002) that suggested that I run this command

```
npm run ionic:serve
```

and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

you should rename you project-folder's name, run **ionic serve** then rename it back and run **ionic serve** again. I don't know why it work, maybe the cache of apache server was saving some temporary data that can't delete because it defined that the project is still running (just my opinion).